# How do you get around ember-sauve notifications about Ember params not being camelCase?

Tags: ember.js

Ember route params have the convention of being underscore, however, ember-suave/jscsrc complains about these params not being camelCase. How do you fix/get around this issue?

Also related, how do I ignore this camelCase message created from third-party plugins that I have no control over with api's that use underscores instead of camelCase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created by own `.jscsrc` file and added the following config:

```
{
  "requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers": "ignoreProperties"
}
```